# Element bloquote not allowed as child of element div in this context

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have validated **HTML5 code** from **W3C validator**. The following error it gives:

> Error: Element bloquote not allowed as child of element div in this
>   context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

**How to fix it?**

```
<div class="col span-1-of-3">
        <bloquote>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus, harum nisi saepe sint dolores rerum, facere laborum dolore fugit laboriosam rem architecto!
               <cite><img src="resources/img/customer-1.jpg" alt="Alberto Duncan">Alberto Duncan</cite>
        </bloquote>
</div>
```

Comment: <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                <bloquote>
                   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis velit quae expedita unde aliquid consequuntur nemo 
                    <cite><img src="resources/img/customer-1.jpg" alt="Alberto Duncan">Alberto Duncan</cite>
                </bloquote>
            </div>                                                                                                           
     This is my code!

Comment: The problem was caused by a typo (the element name is spelt `blockquote` with a `k`). Voting to close as off-topic.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's a typo: you wrote "bloquote" but is "blockquote"

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow.